# Brightway2: Problems importing ecoinvent 3.6 (ecospold files)

Tags: python, brightway

I want to import ecoinvent 3.6 is a database in my brightway2 project.
I have downloaded the required ecospold data files from Ecoinvent, however I get the following error:

```
fpei36 = r"C:~\ecoinvent_36_cut-off_lci_ecoSpold02.7z" # name of path 
ei36 = bw.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(fpei36, 'ecoinvent 3.6 cutoff')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       ei36 = bw.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(fpei36, 'ecoinvent 3.6 cutoff')
>
> File "~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\ecospold2.py",
>   line 67, in **init**
>       self.data = extractor.extract(dirpath, db_name, use_mp=use_mp)
>
> File "~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bw2io\extractors\ecospold2.py",
>   line 93, in extract
>       data = [p.get() for p in results]
>
> File "~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bw2io\extractors\ecospold2.py",
>   line 93, in 
>       data = [p.get() for p in results]
>
> File "~\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
>       raise self._value
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position
>   2: invalid start byte

I would not know 1) what is wrong and b) how I can fix what is going wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the path to a zip (.7z) file. The `dirpath` argument should instead be the path to a directory with the *files* contained in the zip file.

To get going, simply unzip the file first, and then change your code to `fpei36 = r"C:~\path_to_dir_with_thousands_of_ecospold_files"`

You can unzip the file in Python, see [here](https://pypi.org/project/libarchive/) for example. You can also simply unzip it using a tool such as [this](https://www.7-zip.org/) before you get coding.